# Recursion with Lua in Redis

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I read the documentation on scripting in lua for redis and I didnot find any line or recommendation on what i am proposing next being evil or if I am crossing any implied line. So asking this on S.O to confirm..

I have redis script, pseudo like follows

`EVAL "return  redis.call('EVALSHA',ARGV[1],1, redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]),ARGV[2])" 1 foo c664a3bf70bd1d45c4284ffebb65a6f2299bfc9f bar`

and pseudo for c664a3bf70bd1d45c4284ffebb65a6f2299bfc9f script is

`return redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])`

Question is did my script voilate any rules of programmatic key generation? as far as i can think no cause first script actually made a call to the correct key it was invoked with while the second script made the set call for the keys it was invoked with will this cause any issues running on  cluster and non-cluster environments where keys can be spread across nodes? or anything wrong in this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `EVALSHA` is NOT allowed in Lua script, unless you enabled debugging mode.

Run `EVALSHA` in Lua script is dangerous, since you might run into infinite recursion. Say, someone calls `SCRIPT LOAD` with your script, and pass the returned evalsha value to the script. Oops!

Also in your case, the key in the inner script, i.e. `return redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])`, is dynamically generated with a `GET` call. This key might be in a different hash slot of the outer script key, and it will be a problem if you run the script in Redis Cluster.

Comment: Oh, that's sad EVALSHA cannot run inside Redis, my use-case was tree traversal looks like it wont be possible with redis unless i remodel data structure.

Comment: Just of curiosity is recursion allowed with functions?, also the idea of passing a key to a completely different invocation of eval should have handled programmatic keys cause its just like calling from any other client..

Comment: Also can you point out exactly where you read this in documentation, it will help for reference

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to check the source code. Also, you can do some test by running a script with evalsha called, and you'll get an error message.